# Remove unwanted multibyte characters without harming "foreign" characters

Tags: php, regex, replace, unicode, sanitization

What is the best way to remove unwanted unicode characters without breaking other foreign characters?

็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ ็็็็็็็็็

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter the right Unicode ranges, this should work:

```
$str = 'Your string with Unicode symbols'
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/EY06F

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php